# Piping FFmpeg output to Unity texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, encoding, ffmpeg, textures, pipeline

I'm working on a networking component where the **server** provides a Texture and sends it to FFmpeg to be encoded (h264_qsv), and sends it over the network. The **client** receives the stream (mp4 presumably), decodes it using FFmpeg again and displays it on a Texture.

Currently this works very slowly since I am saving the texture to the disk before encoding it to a mp4 file (also saved to disk), and on the client side I am saving the .png texture to disk after decoding it so that I could use it in Unity.

Server side FFmpeg process is started with `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -y -i testimg.png -c:v h264_qsv -q 5 -look_ahead 0 -preset:v faster -crf 0 test.qsv.mp4";` currently and client side with `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -y -i test.qsv.mp4 output.png";`

Since this needs to be **very fast** (30 fps at least) and real time, I need to **pipe the Texture directly** to the FFmpeg process. On the client side, I need to **pipe the decoded data to the displayed Texture** directly as well (opposed to saving it and then reading from disk).

A few days of researching showed me that FFmpeg supports various pipelining options, including using data formats such as *bmp_pipe* (piped bmp sequence), *bin*(binary text), *data* (raw data) and *image2pipe* (piped image2 sequence) however documentation and examples on how to use these options are very scarce.

Please help me: which format should I use (and how should it be used) ?

Comment: You wrote all these without even proving a single code you currenlty use to read from ffmpeg. If someone is supposed to help you, do you expect them to start from scratch and post a complete solution?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "read from ffmpeg"? I wrote the two lines I feed into the process arguments started from Unity, one for server-side encoding and the other for client-side decoding. I expect guidance and a few hints on what I need to do as an answer, not the complete solution code.